# jOOQ - Using runtime mapping with manually created fields

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In my project I have a problematic table (named `PROBLEMATIC` here) consisting of a few columns that always exists (defined in schema, for example: `id`), and other columns are added or removed dynamically when the application works. I can make use of these "dynamic" columns with a simple function that returns appropriate `Field` objects:

```
public static <T> Field<T> getField(String fieldName, Class<T> type) {
  return DSL.field(DSL.name(PROBLEMATIC.getName(), fieldName), type);
}
```

That function works well and I can create jOOQ queries using the `Field` objects it returns.

The problem began when I wanted to add a runtime mapping that would rename this problematic table in rendered queries.

```
Settings settings = new Settings()
    .withRenderSchema(false)
    .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.QUOTED)
    .withRenderCatalog(false)
    .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
        .withSchemata(new MappedSchema()
            .withInput("PUBLIC")
            .withTables(
                new MappedTable().withInput("problematic").withOutput("another_problematic")
            )
        ));
```

When I create a simple query using jOOQ, the mapping works partially.

```
dsl.select(PROBLEMATIC.ID, getField("dynamic1", String.class), getField("dynamic2", String.class))
   .from(PROBLEMATIC)
   .fetch();
```

Rendered query:

```
select "another_problematic"."id", "problematic"."dynamic1", "problematic"."dynamic2" from "another_problematic"
```

The problem is: jOOQ properly replaced a table name for those columns which are defined in schema and for the `FROM` clause. Fields for columns created using the `DSL.field()` method weren't affected.

How can I use runtime mapping in such situation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in jOOQ: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8991. At least, it is for `DSL.field(Name)` calls, which produces qualified field references.

A workaround is to dereference the column directly from your `PROBLEMATIC` table, e.g.

```
public static <T> Field<T> field(String fieldName, Class<T> type) {
    return PROBLEMATIC.field(fieldName, type);
}
```

Note that for the avoidance of doubt: `DSL.field(String, Class<?>)` calls are part of the [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). There might as well be any expression in there, including `field("a + b")`. As jOOQ does not parse these expressions, no schema mapping could possibly apply there. I know you're not doing this, but someone else might be, who is reading this question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I did as you suggested, then my field is not show in query at all. I also edited my code and renamed the `field()` method; you were right it might be confusing.

Comment: @itachi: The field names are case sensitive in Java / jOOQ. Did you choose the right case?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sensitive on this, as I work with PostgreSQL which doesn't tolerate similar mistakes.

Comment: The reason why `PROBLEMATIC.field()` didn't work for me is that it looks for fields defined in schema, and since my dynamic fields are not defined there, then it can't find them and returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I've came up with a workaround that might be helpful for others.

## ATTENTION!

This **workaround** adds fields but **doesn't remove them**, there isn't any method allowing this kind of operation (that's obvious, why remove fields from a table?). This is not a problem in my case because if the dynamic schema changes, the application is restarted anyway, but if you mangle your table frequently without restarting, the class holding all these fields will start to grow uncontrollably.

## Workaround

I spotted that I can utilise `AbstractTable.createField()` method, and fields created with that method are mapped properly. The same method is being used by table classes generated by jOOQ to initialise their fields. Since this method is protected, one must create an extending class that is a wrapper for the class with dynamic fields (`Problematic` in my case).

```
public class DynamicProblematic extends Problematic {
    public static final DynamicProblematic DYNAMIC_PROBLEMATIC = new DynamicProblematic();

    private Map<String, TableField<ProblematicRecord, ?>> dynamicFields = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> TableField<ProblematicRecord, T> dynamicField(String fieldName, Class<T> type) {
        if (!dynamicFields.containsKey(fieldName)) {
            if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
              dynamicFields.put(fieldName, createField(fieldName, SQLDataType.INTEGER, this, ""));
            } else {
              dynamicFields.put(fieldName, createField(fieldName, SQLDataType.CLOB, this, ""));
            }
        }

        return (TableField<ProblematicRecord, T>) dynamicFields.get(fieldName);
    }
}
```

The `DynamicProblematic.dynamicField()` method might be implemented accordingly to your needs. I needed a method accepting a field name and a type, that might be an Integer or a String in my case, and I don't expect another type to be passed, so it's satisfactory.

I decided to store created fields in a `HashMap` and reuse them, because every call to the `AbstractTable.createField()` eventually adds the created field to a table instance and that would grow after each call to the `DynamicProblematic.dynamicField()`.

I'm not accepting my answer as an answer, because this is not what I eventually need.

Comment: This approach is using internal API. I'm sure you're aware of the risks this creates, as the API might change incompatibly at any moment. We're aware that the functionality offered by internal API would be useful to users as well through public API, which we'll offer in the future: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7444

Comment: @LukasEder I'm aware, I keep it in my mind and I will change this part of code as soon as it will be possible.

Comment: I know you're aware, I'm just afraid of this having been "documented" on stack overflow now, for others to blindly copy paste :) Which puts some pressure on #7444, so maybe not a bad strategy on your part ;)